# How to access an inner website from aapanel url?

Tags: wordpress

I've just installed aapanel on a VPS for the first time and I am excited about all the possibilities I have now.
I am going to use some fake name to explain what I want to do. For example, my aapanel is accessable from aa.domain.com

I created a wordpress installation named abc.com (root/www/wwwroot/abc.com), which is shown at the AApanel's Website pages. I'm going to point my real domin to this installation, but in the meanwhile during develop and setup, I would like to access this wordpress using my aapanel url on my browser, lke aa.domain.com/wordpress. Is that possible?

Which is address should I put on my address bar to get to wordpress?

I tried accessing the website usin aa.domain.com/abc in order to access my wordpress homepage.